# Convert json to string in java

Tags: java, android, json, string

How I can put a complicated json object in an array of strings?

**JSON sample**

```
{
  "FriendsList": [
    {
      "username": "ChanServ",
      "avatar": "http:\/\/clavatars.photos-box.org\/chack.jpg"
    },
    {
      "username": "kroot",
      "avatar": "http:\/\/clavatars.photos-box.org\/land2.jpg"
    },
    {
      "username": "morrildl",
      "avatar": "http:\/\/clavatars.photos-box.org\/land3.jpg"
    },
    {
      "username": "addo",
      "avatar": "http:\/\/clavatars.photos-box.org\/land8.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is the code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    JSONObject json;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(result);
        tvhttp.setText(json.toString(2));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: tvhttp.setText(result);  result is already string right? what are you tryin to do actually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("FriendsList");

        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject jsonObjectData1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

            String username = jsonObjectData1.getString("username");
            String avatar = jsonObjectData1.getString("avatar");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**   Try this code...**

```
 JSONObject json = null;
 ArrayList<String> userNameList=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> avatarList=new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    json = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("FriendsList");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObjectData1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String username = jsonObjectData1.getString("username");
        String avatar = jsonObjectData1.getString("avatar");
        userNameList.add(username);
        avatarList.add(avatar);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```